# Magento Redirect all .htaccess keeping administration

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

We did our new website and currently we have both in our host. We have made a 301 redirect from old site to new site.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/new/ [NC]
RewriteRule !^new/ /new%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

Right now, everything is redirect to /new but we need to keep old admin. Is any way to redirect everything but keeping the old website administration?

we can go to new site at: mywebsite.com/new/index.php/admin
we want to do the same to the old one: mywebsite.com/index.php/admin

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try your .htaccess this way.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php/admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/new/ [NC]
RewriteRule !^new/ /new%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Jack, thanks for your quickly reply. Is working fine thanks.